# PHP loses data from Jquery .serialize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to send the values of multiple select box to a mail/check script with ajax
But when the variable reaches the php script the array lost its first record and i cant find how

```
jQuery(function() {
    var paraTag = jQuery('input#submit').parent('div');
    jQuery(paraTag).children('input').remove();
    jQuery(paraTag).append('<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Verstuur" />');

jQuery('#contact-form input#submit').click(function() {
    jQuery('#contact-form').append('<img src="images/loading.gif" class="loaderIcon" style="width:100px; margin:-20px;" alt="Loading..." />');

    var name = jQuery('input#name').val();
    var adres = jQuery('input#adres').val();
    var woonplaats = jQuery('input#woonplaats').val();
    var email = jQuery('input#email').val();
    var postcode = jQuery('input#postcode').val();
    var bedrijf = jQuery('input#bedrijf').val();
    var comments = jQuery('textarea#comments').val();
    var tel = jQuery('input#tel2').val();
    var hidden = jQuery('input#hidden2').val();         
    var over_select =  jQuery('#over').serialize();


    console.log(over_select);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'sendEmail.php',
        data: 'hidden=' + hidden + '&over=' + over_select + '&post=' + postcode + '&plaats=' + woonplaats + '&adres=' + adres +'&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&tel=' + tel + '&bedrijf=' + bedrijf + '&comments=' + comments,

        success: function(results) {
            jQuery('#contact-form img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
            jQuery('#response').html(results);
        }
    }); // end ajax
});
```

In the mail script i put "over" in a php variable and when i print_r() it, it lost its first selection.
Can you please help me out?

Comment: Where is the PHP code?

Comment: And at the start of the PHP code, do this to see what it's input is: `print_r($_POST);die();`

Comment: the php file just has $over = $_POST['over']; and return print_r($over);

Comment: You cannot do `return print_r($over);` It needs to be: `echo print_r($over,true);` although I dont know why anyone would want to do that

Comment: With >print_r($_POST);die(); It already lost its first value of the selection

Comment: the return is for testing purpose now. normally it just returns an error from the form e.g. wrong email

Comment: I console.log the selection which gives "over%5B%5D=Bike+Patrol&over%5B%5D=Camera+toezicht"  but when the php shows it, it lost the "Bike Patrol"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending your data like this

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'sendEmail.php',
        data : {'hidden': hidden, 'over': over_select, 'post': postcode, 'plaats': woonplaats, 'adres': adres,'name':name,'email': email, 'tel': tel, 'bedrijf':bedrijf, 'comments': comments},
        success: function(results) {
            jQuery('#contact-form img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
            jQuery('#response').html(results);
        }
    }); // end ajax
```

Then in the php part use

```
url_decode($_POST['over_select']);
```

Comment: read ajax documentation: `data Type: PlainObject or String or Array`. It could be string.

Comment: This does return the full value `over%5B%5D=Bike+Patrol&over%5B%5D=Camera+toezicht` Anyway i can get it with spaces etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you run .serialize() on your multiple select it will return something like this:

> over[]=Val1&over[]=Val2

Your data string then becomes:

> over=over[]=Val1&over[]=Val2

Which is probably your problem. Try removing the "over=" in your data string.